# How can I open two terminals side-by-side in PhpStorm?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

I'm aware that you can open multiple terminals by clicking the plus button on the terminal window (but this lets you switch between tabs/terminals in a tab menu).

But I've had it where two terminals are splitting the width of the bottom area of my IDE by 50% each. I can only seem to do this randomly by accident. What is the setting or process to do this on purpose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've managed to get this working by:

1. Right-clicking on a file (in the main editor window), clicking Split horizontally.
2. Splitting that view again vertically.
3. Moving the terminal window into one of the above splits.
4. Moving the other terminal window into the other.
5. Closing or moving your file back up to the main editor window.

[image: web editor splitting work around]

You can then close the normal terminal area at the bottom of your IDE and it works good enough. Would like to see if they could just support split-terminals without this work around.

Answer (score 0):

Not currently supported, please follow [IDEA-141172](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-141172) for updates